# Why React JS useEffect is running on every rerender inspite of having an empty dependency array?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I am creating a small to-do-list app. Now on loading I want to check if the user already registered or not by getting data from local storage and I want this check to run on only initial rerender, but the problem here is this is running on every time user signed in to another account or create a new account.

So, is there any way to prevent this, or I am doing something wrong?
I am a noob in react, so sorry if I made any silly mistake :-<

```
const Home = () => {
  const { dispatch } = useGlobalAppContext();
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getLocalStorage = async () => {
      try {
        const [email, password] = JSON.parse(
          localStorage.getItem("team-manager")
        );
        if (email && password) {
          const userModel = { email, password };
          const newUser = await axios.post(
            "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/user/signin",
            userModel
          );
          history.push("/");
          dispatch({ type: "SIGNIN__USER", payload: newUser.data.data });
          console.log("I am home");
        } else {
          history.push("/register");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        history.push("/register");
      }
    };

    getLocalStorage();
  }, []);
  return (
    <HomeWrapper>
      <Prompt />
      <TaskPopup />
      <SearchPanel />
      <Sidebar />
      <TaskPanel />
      <ChatPanel />
    </HomeWrapper>
  );
};
```

**and this is the Signin component**

```
const Signin = () => {
  const { dispatch } = useGlobalAppContext();
 
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  
  const [disabled,setDisabled]=useState(false)
  const history=useHistory()

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setDisabled(true)
    try {
      const userModel = {email, password};
      const newUser = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/user/signin",
        userModel
      );
      dispatch({type:"SIGNIN__USER",payload:newUser.data.data})
      history.push("/")
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error?.response.data.message);
      dispatch({type:"OPEN_MODEL",payload:{errorMessage:error?.response.data.message,typeOfAlert:"danger"}})
    }
    finally{
      setDisabled(false)
      localStorage.setItem("team-manager",JSON.stringify([email,password]))
    }
  };
    return (
      <PageWrapper>
        <FormWrapper>
          <img
            src={SigninImage}
            alt="Create an accout to start using the app"
            className="page__img"
          />
          <main className="page__details">
            <h1 className="page__heading">Sign In</h1>
            <Form action="" method="POST" className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <div className="form__inputs">
                <input value={email} onChange={e=>setEmail(e.target.value)} name="email" required placeholder="Email"type="email" className="form__email" />
                <input value={password} onChange={e=>setPassword(e.target.value)} name="password" required placeholder="Password"type="password" className="form__password" />
              </div>
              <Button type="submit" className="form__btn" disabled={disabled}>
                Sign in
              </Button>
              <Link to="/"className="form__btn form__btn--secondary">
                Back to home page
              </Link>
              <h3 className="secondary__link">Don't have an account?<Link to="/register">Create a new one</Link></h3>
            </Form>
          </main>
        </FormWrapper>
      </PageWrapper>
    );
  };
  

export default Signin
```

Comment: This code seems ok. Somehow any other code is unmounting the components on create and signed in. Can you create a dummy codesandbox and share it

Comment: From the code it seems ok. I have to run it.

Comment: can you please check by running it when you are free? you just need to open a free mongodb atlas account in order to run it . I still can not figure it out :-<

Comment: @moshfiqrony I think there is some problem in **signin componenet**. I have uploaded the signIn code in question. Can I you please take a look at this?

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem in the signin components. If the use effect is executing without any reason that must the component is mounting and un mounting for any logic

Comment: @moshfiqrony I have figured it out!! There was a form which was reloading the page on submitting, that's why it was unmouting the componenents.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help that much